# API 15 Fragment or Support.v4.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Small question:
I'm developping an app for Android API 15 and up. Should I use Fragment or Support.v4.Fragment?
I already use Support.v7.AppCompatActivity to support my toolbar but for my fragments, what's the best one to use with my minimum API?

Thanks!

Comment: what about fx.: [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) ? ... for your sanity it would be better to use at least `v13.Fragment` ... I choose to use v4 as it behave same on all platform and not depend on default/orginal/framework Fragment's implementation ... but of course it is **primarily opinion-based** (as all question which starts with *what's the best ...*)

Comment: if he needs nested fragments then I agree, it should go with support libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using just fragments you don't need support libraries since Fragments are introduced in API 11.